# Avoid " has no parameter named" error in Sass Mixins

Tags: sass

I'm wondering how I need to write SASS mixins that accept a defined list of arguments with default values and ignore all other arguments. Basically I'd like to know how I would have to change  the `@mixin dummy` so it doesn't throw me a "**Mixin dummy has no parameter named $xyz**" error.

```
@mixin dummy(
  $a: true,
  $b: false,
  $c: auto
) {
  // do stuff
}

$params: (
  a: false,
  xyz: 'foo'
);

@include dummy($params...);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append `...` to `$params` to expand it into an args list.

```
$params: (
  a: false,
  xyz: 'auto'
);
.dummy{
  @include dummy($params...);
}
```

You can inline it too

```
.dummy{
  @include dummy((
    a: false,
    xyz: 'auto'
  )...);
}
```

More at https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-multiple-arguments-lists-or-arglist/

Answer (score 0):

Use arglist to get the mixin parameters:

```
@mixin dummy(
  $a: true,
  $c: auto,
  $args...
) {
  height:#{map-get($params,xyz)};
}

$params: (
  a: false,
  xyz: 'auto'
);
.dummy{
  @include dummy($params);
}


/*Outputs*/

.dummy {
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really have the desired effect. If I `@debug $a` in your code it won't return false, but `(a: false, xyz: 'auto')` so I lose access to the default value. I did quite some investigation on this issue and I think there's simply no way for what I'm trying to achieve. But thanks for your help anyway =) My workaround solution atm is to simply define all possible named arguments with the default value of `null` to avoid the error.